# How to install php-cli without root permissions?

Tags: software-installation, php

I need to install `php-cli` but I cannot use `sudo`

How can I do this ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you only need to run it or do you have to install it?

Comment: Ask your sys admin to install it for you ;)

Comment: @the_Seppi I simply need to be able to run some php scripts from the terminal